# Cytoscape js how to get all edges (text label) when clicked on a node

Tags: cytoscape.js

I know that I can use node.connectedEdges() to return an object of the edges connected to that node. How do I access the data fields of all the edges. I want to be able to click on a node and have the connected edges labels (text) in a list.

Also when you click on a node how can you access that nodes meta data (other attributes that are in the nodes JSON object).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, everything in the node/edge metadata is accessible with the [`.data()`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/data) method. This is a core functionality and i would suggest you to look at the [docs](https://js.cytoscape.org/), because this is a fairly simple task. All you have to do is to call the [`.connectedEdges()`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.connectedEdges) method and map the resulting object accordingly (using `.data()`):

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'height': '60px',
        'width': '60px',
        'border-color': 'black',
        'border-opacity': '1',
        'border-width': '10px'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ':selected',
      css: {
        'background-color': 'black',
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'source-arrow-color': 'black'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n0'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n3'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n4'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n5'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n6'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n7'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n8'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n9'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n10'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n11'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n12'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n13'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n14'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n15'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n16'
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: 'n0',
          target: 'n1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n2'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n3'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n2',
          target: 'n7'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n2',
          target: 'n11'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n2',
          target: 'n16'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n3',
          target: 'n4'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n3',
          target: 'n16'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n4',
          target: 'n5'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n4',
          target: 'n6'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n6',
          target: 'n8'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n8',
          target: 'n9'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n8',
          target: 'n10'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n11',
          target: 'n12'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n12',
          target: 'n13'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n13',
          target: 'n14'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n13',
          target: 'n15'
        }
      },
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'dagre',
    padding: 5
  }
});


cy.ready(function() {
  cy.unbind('click')
  cy.bind('click', 'node', function(event) {
    let edges = event.target.connectedEdges().map(edge => edge.data().id)
    console.log(edges)
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-dagre@2.1.0/cytoscape-dagre.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You just need some extra data in the edges and write that key instead of id:
`edge.data().someKey`